# Making A Menu Item Display A Window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have made some code to do this, but as It doesn't work. I am only a beginner so I may be doing this completely wrong or i may have missed something out. Either way please tell me. Here is the code I have got.

```
[item setAction:(SEL)action {
        [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make an anonymous function. AFAIK, Obj-C has no support for these. Basically want you want to do is define `action` as a proper method:

```
[item setAction:@selector(action:)];
```

…

```
-(void)action:(id)sender{  
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];  
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're passing `NSApp` to `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`. The full signature is `- (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)sender`, so passing `self` is usually most appropriate (although I'm not even sure what that input does!).

I suggest you work through a few [tutorials](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html) to familiarize yourself with Obj-C and Cocoa.

Comment: Actually, NSApp is the shared application instance, of type NSApplication.

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know that! I'll edit my post to reflect that. Thanks! To think, all this time I've been using [NSApplication sharedApplication]!

Answer (score 3):

The SEL data type refers to a *selector*, which is a way of referring to a method in a class. What you have to do is define a method in your target object's class:

```
- (void)doSomething:(id)sender {
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}
```

and call your control's setAction: method like this:

```
[item setAction:@selector(doSomething:)];
```

It looks like you need to bone up on the basics of Cocoa, however. May I suggest [Apple's Getting Started guide](http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Cocoa/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001088)